# Scala templates import reusable blocks (Play2)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, scala-template

I'm using Play framework 2.2.4 and Scala templates. I have created base Scala template with many code blocks, which I want to use in multiple views. Something like:

**base.scala.html**

```
@()

@display(product: Product) = {
  @product.name ($@product.price)
}
```

**products.scala.html**

```
...
   @display(product)
...
```

How can I import such file in view to use `@display` block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each view fragment should be in it's own file, with it's own parameters declared there. A Play template is supposed to work like a *single function*, not many. Instead, create a directory called `base`, and separate the view fragments into separate files.

**views/base/display.scala.html**

```
@(product: Product)

@product.name ($@product.price)
```

**views/products.scala.html**

```
...
    @base.display(product)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a separate file, `display.scala.html` and make it the only/actual template, the file name is the fragment/function name:

```
@(product: Product)

@product.name ($@product.price)
```

if in the same package just call it

```
@display(product)
```

or if in another package either use full package name or import it first

```
@some.package.display(product)

@import some.package.display

@display(product)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [templating doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTemplateUseCases), section: **Tags (they are just functions right?)**

In general you can i.e. move your *block* to `views/tags/displayProduct.scala.html` (and use it as common template) so you can use it in ANY view with:

```
<div class="product">
    @tags.displayProduct(product)
</div>
```